# Technology stack for mobile based internal tools

Tags: mobile

I'm building an mobile based internal tool for a company. But I'm not able to figure out the programming stack to use. I mean, I have read that only native, hybrid or web based apps can be built on phones but I'm not looking for web based and we don't want to bring the app to the app store since it's only for the company people. Any suggestions on how to approach here?

Comment: If you don't/can't publish the app on the iOS store, then you're probably out of luck for iOS, since Apple would forbid you from mass-deploying a custom app on many phones.  For Android, you _might_ be OK with doing a custom deployment of an app.  What is the problem with the store?  You can always just prevent people from creating an account who are not part of your organization.

Comment: There is no problem as such. Yeah, we can prevent other people but I was just looking at alternatives.

Comment: I think Android might work with what you have in mind.  But this presupposes that all your users would have an Android phone (probably not the case).

Comment: Yeah, that's there. Thanks for the info. I'll mostly go with cross platform development.